# How to create a contextual filter using a current user multivalue field as the default value

Tags: 7, views

How to create a contextual filter using a current user multivalue field as the default value?

The idea is to filter content in a view, based on a value present in a multivalue field that the currently logged in user account has.

I tried using views php in the default contextual filter:

$user_profile = user_load($user->uid);
$statusvalue= $user_profile->field_status['und'][0]['value'];
return $statusvalue;

..but that works for a single value and thus does not work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:
I accomplished this without using a contextual filter.
The view can be based on entities.
(Alternative solution is to use a user view, slightly different config)

I added the field two times, of which one uses the relationship to the user.

Then added the fillter 'global: field comparison' and selected both fields.

As a bonus I added a filter, using OR switch, to allow a specific user field value for showing all content.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your contextual filter go to bottom and in tab "more" check "allow multiple value" checkbox and return value 1+2+3 (OR) or 1,2,3 (AND).

Comment: I tried that checkbox, but using my php code that doesnt work for me.